# Marklogic scheduled backups failing

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

We are currently using scheduled backups to have daily database backups. We are observing many problems in taking backups from past few days. The backup process executes for several hours but didn't get completed. We also had a look at the logs, but there is nothing mentioned for scheduled backup. We have following questions -

1. By any means, can we make it more consistent and stop such things?
2. Is there a way to get some kind of notification/email after the certain time if scheduled backup isn't successfully completed until that time.
3. Can we also have a retry mechanism on the failure of scheduled backup?

Comment: What about the database status page?  Does it show the db as still backing up?  What 'file log level' are you running at?  Some messages will show up at the `Info` level, others will show up at the `Warning` or 'error' level.  Do you see [Canceling backup] in the errorlog?  The messages are logged to the host that the forest is attached to, so if the db backup fails it will cancel all the other associated forest backups - and write the canceling message to the attached host, and the error that stopped the backup will log to its attached host.  Do you have sufficient space on backup drive?

Answer (score 3):

For your points:

1) If you don't describe he failures, there is little people can do to give guidance.

2) The forest backup information is logged. You can use standard log monitoring/alerting tools to manage alerts. Keep in mind that the log messages are per forest, so you may need to look closely at the lg messages for when a 'complete' or 'failed' backup are done.

3) From the result of number (2), you may decide to kick-off a new backup via the management API. See here: http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]#BackupDB

Comment: The scheduled job for backup is running and is not terminating. It is not logging anything in logs. It is just showing backup in progress for long time.

Comment: @AnkitBhardwaj It gives an estimated completion time for the backup on the Database status page, as well on each individual forest page.  Are those accurate?

Comment: It is showing 00:37:43 for one of the forests, for others it is showing unknown.

Comment: @AnkitBhardwaj Are there disk contention or network contention issues?  Are you overwhelming the backup location with write requests?  In one of the environments I work in, we see forest backups take 4-6 hours, but an individual forest can backup in 2-3 hours.